# In UFT 14.0, on error pop up message does not display

Tags: uft14

In UFT 14.0, on error, my pop up message does not display.

I had kept the setting File > Setting > Run > while run if error occurs, pop up message is to be displayed.

Still on error it moves to the next step and execution continues. Please suggest how this could be corrected.

Comment: Do you have `On Error Resume Next` anywhere in your code? If so pls remove it and try again.

Comment: @ManishChristian - I have checked, there are no "On Error resume next" used in the scripting. Don't if I am missing any other setting in UFT.

Comment: What kind of errors you are referring to? Can you give example code snippet?